# 'Photo' object is not iterable

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-forms

I have a web page that show the details that is from my database, but when the user click on the view button, it did redirect me to the details page and get the id, but at the same time it give me an error 'Photo' object is not iterable, what is wrong with my code? How do I fix the error?

Error:
[image]

traceback error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/details/6/

Django Version: 2.2.20
Python Version: 3.8.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'account.apps.AccountConfig',
 'crispy_forms']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django_session_timeout.middleware.SessionTimeoutMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template E:\Role_based_login_system-master\templates\logisticbase.html, error at line 67
   'Photo' object is not iterable
   57 :                 &lt;/div&gt;
   58 :             {% endfor %}
   59 :         {% endif %}
   60 :         &lt;div id="home_body"&gt;
   61 :             {% block content %}
   62 : 
   63 :             {% endblock %}
   64 :         &lt;/div&gt;
   65 :         &lt;!-- Optional JavaScript --&gt;
   66 :         &lt;!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS --&gt;
   67 :         &lt;script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT 7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4Y fRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
   68 :         &lt;script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
   69 :         &lt;script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
   70 :     &lt;/body&gt;
   71 : &lt;/html&gt;

Traceback:

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "E:\Role_based_login_system-master\account\views.py" in details
  312.     return render(request, 'details.html', context)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\TAY\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  165.                 values = list(values)

Exception Type: TypeError at /details/6/
Exception Value: 'Photo' object is not iterable
```

views.py

```
@login_required()
def details(request, pk):

    allusername = Photo.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'allusername': allusername}
    print(pk)
    return render(request, 'details.html', context)
```

details.html

```
    {% extends "logisticbase.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    <style>
    table {
        border-collapse:separate;
        border:solid black 1px;
        border-radius:6px;
        -moz-border-radius:6px;
    }
    
    td, th {
        border-left:solid black 1px;
        border-top:solid black 1px;
    }
    
    th {
        border-top: none;
    }
    
    td:first-child, th:first-child {
         border-left: none;
    }
    
    
    
    </style>
    <script>
      
    
     // Function to download table data into csv file
            function download_table_as_csv(table_id, separator = ',') {
                var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table#' + table_id + ' tr');
                var csv = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td, th');
                    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
                        var data = cols[j].innerText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '').replace(/(\s\s)/gm, ' ')
                        data = data.replace(/"/g, '""');
                        row.push('"' + data + '"');
                    }
                    csv.push(row.join(separator));
                }
                var csv_string = csv.join('\n');
                var filename = 'export_' + table_id + '_' + new Date().toLocaleDateString() + '.csv';
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.style.display = 'none';
                link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv_string));
                link.setAttribute('download', filename);
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            };
    
    </script>
    
    
       <div style="padding-left:16px">
         <br>
    
    
     <div class="form-block">
         <h5>Search for Part Number/ Reception Number/ Customer Name</h5>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'gallery' %}" method='GET' value='{{ request.GET.q }}'>
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="q" value='{{ request.GET.q }}'/>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
         <br>
       <table id="viewTable" class="m-2">
            <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <a href="#" onclick="download_table_as_csv('viewTable');">Download as CSV</a>
           <br>
    
      <tr class="header">
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Log date</th>

      </tr>
             {% for photo in allusername %}

    
      <tr>
            <td>{{photo.Datetime}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.status}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.Datetime}}</td>

    
      </tr>

    {% endfor %}

    </table>
         <br>
    
    
    
    
    </div>
       </div>

{% endblock %}
```

gallery.html

```
{% extends "logisticbase.html" %}
    {% block content %}
    <style>
    table {
        border-collapse:separate;
        border:solid black 1px;
        border-radius:6px;
        -moz-border-radius:6px;
    }
    
    td, th {
        border-left:solid black 1px;
        border-top:solid black 1px;
    }
    
    th {
        border-top: none;
    }
    
    td:first-child, th:first-child {
         border-left: none;
    }
    
    
    
    </style>
    <script>
      
    
     // Function to download table data into csv file
            function download_table_as_csv(table_id, separator = ',') {
                var rows = document.querySelectorAll('table#' + table_id + ' tr');
                var csv = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    var row = [], cols = rows[i].querySelectorAll('td, th');
                    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
                        var data = cols[j].innerText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, '').replace(/(\s\s)/gm, ' ')
                        data = data.replace(/"/g, '""');
                        row.push('"' + data + '"');
                    }
                    csv.push(row.join(separator));
                }
                var csv_string = csv.join('\n');
                var filename = 'export_' + table_id + '_' + new Date().toLocaleDateString() + '.csv';
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.style.display = 'none';
                link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
                link.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv_string));
                link.setAttribute('download', filename);
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            };
    
    </script>
    
    
       <div style="padding-left:16px">
         <br>
    
    
     <div class="form-block">
         <h5>Search for Part Number/ Reception Number/ Customer Name</h5>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'gallery' %}" method='GET' value='{{ request.GET.q }}'>
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="q" value='{{ request.GET.q }}'/>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
         <br>
       <table id="viewTable" class="m-2">
            <i class="fa fa-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <a href="#" onclick="download_table_as_csv('viewTable');">Download as CSV</a>
           <br>
    
      <tr class="header">
        <th>Latest Log</th>
          <th>Part Number</th>
          <th>Serial Number</th>
          <th>Reception/MCO Number</th>
          <th>Customer Name</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>View</th>
      </tr>
             {% for photo in allusername %}
    
    
      <tr>
            <td>{{photo.Datetime}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.partno}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.serialno}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.reception}}/ {{photo.mcoNum}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.Customername}}</td>
          <td>{{photo.status}}</td>
          <td>
              <form action="{% url 'details' photo.id %}" method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">View</button>
      </form>
          </td>
    
      </tr>
    
    {% endfor %}
    
    </table>
         <br>
    
    
    
    
    </div>
       </div>

{% endblock %}
```

This is how my gallery page looks like, so when the user click on the view button, it should get the ID and redirect them to the details page and view more in depth detail that is from the database.

[image]

Comment: Isn't the error message pretty clear? `objects.get(...)` method returns a single object and you're trying to iterate over it. This is basic Django stuff and similar questions already exist on this site. Please do some research before posting questions. SO is not a code debugging service.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django model is not iterable in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356031/django-model-is-not-iterable-in-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside your details.html
change this

```
         {% for photo in allusername %}


       <tr>
        <td>{{photo.Datetime}}</td>
      <td>{{photo.status}}</td>
      <td>{{photo.Datetime}}</td>


  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

to

```
           <tr>
        <td>{{allusername.Datetime}}</td>
      <td>{{allusername.status}}</td>
      <td>{{allusername.Datetime}}</td>


  </tr>
```

the problem is that you are using a for loop over a non iterable object.

Comment: not sure if you can help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69432282/link-mco-number-to-reception-number

Answer (score 1):

When you use the get method in a queryset it will return only one object if found or a query does not exist error in that case if the object is not found. So you were trying to iterate over a single element that's why you are getting this error.

Just remove the for loop and maintian the rest of code like below.

```
  <!-- not to include    {% for photo in allusername %} -->    
  <tr>
      <td>{{allusername.Datetime}}</td>
      <td>{{allusername.status}}</td>
      <td>{{allusername.Datetime}}</td>    
  </tr>

  <!-- {% endfor %}  -->
```

Comment: this is not correct.please try to edit your answer."photo" is not inside the context.instead of photo it should be "allusername".

Comment: done sorry for that silly mistake